# Сборка QEMU 6.0 - отсутствует qemu-img

Tags: linux, build, qemu

В процессе сборки QEMU версии 6 не собирается qemu-img, хотя, вроде бы, должен.

Сборка:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu.git
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --bindir=/usr/bin --libdir=/usr/lib64 --datadir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/qemu-6.0.0/html --mandir=/usr/share/man --localstatedir=/var --disable-bsd-user --disable-containers --disable-guest-agent --disable-strip --disable-tcg-interpreter --disable-werror --disable-gcrypt --disable-debug-info --disable-debug-tcg --enable-docs --enable-gettext --disable-plugins --enable-attr --disable-brlapi --enable-linux-aio --enable-bzip2 --disable-capstone --enable-cap-ng --enable-curl --enable-fdt --disable-glusterfs --disable-gnutls --disable-nettle --disable-gtk --disable-rdma --disable-libiscsi --disable-linux-io-uring --disable-jemalloc --enable-vnc-jpeg --enable-kvm --disable-lzo --disable-mpath --enable-curses --disable-libnfs --disable-numa --enable-opengl --enable-vnc-png --disable-rbd --disable-vnc-sasl --enable-sdl --disable-sdl-image --enable-seccomp --enable-slirp=system --disable-smartcard --disable-snappy --enable-spice --disable-libssh --disable-libudev --enable-libusb --enable-usb-redir --disable-vde --enable-vhost-net --disable-vhost-user-fs --disable-virtiofsd --disable-virglrenderer --enable-virtfs --enable-vnc --disable-vte --disable-xen --disable-xen-pci-passthrough --disable-xfsctl --disable-xkbcommon --disable-zstd --enable-libxml2 --audio-drv-list=sdl,oss, --disable-linux-user --enable-system --disable-tools --target-list=i386-softmmu,x86_64-softmmu --enable-pie
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

В итоге получается:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep qemu
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    15390896 Jun  8 09:30 qemu-system-i386
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    15434784 Jun  8 09:30 qemu-system-x86_64
```

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 6.0.50 (v6.0.0-1496-g33ba8b0adc)
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Видно, что qemu-img отсутствует (`find` также не принес результата).

Версия ОС:

```html
$ uname -r
4.19.0-14-amd64
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Devuan GNU/Linux 3 (beowulf)"
NAME="Devuan GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="3"
VERSION="3 (beowulf)"
VERSION_CODENAME=beowulf
ID=devuan
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.devuan.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://devuan.org/os/community"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.devuan.org/"
```

Comment: `--disable-tools` — вы сами отключили сборку qemu-img

Comment: @andreymal, действительно так. Можете создать ответ, и я отмечу его как верный, если хотите. Спасибо!